# Why doesnt my servlet show in Selenium Grid

Tags: java, servlets, selenium-grid

I've made a servlet for selenium grid and from what I can see i've followed all of the information on the selenium (not much on there actually) but I still dont get it.

Here is the code inside my servlet:

```
package servletPackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Servlet
 */
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("test");
        PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
        write.println("This is <b>bold</b>");
    }

}
```

And i'm launching my grid hub like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar -role hub -port 4444 -servlets servletPackage.Servlet
```

The problem is when I hit the page http://localhost:4444/grid/admin/Servlet I get a whoops page. I dont understand where i'm going wrong here. Is there an error in my code? I didnt see it throw any exceptions when the grid launched.

Edit: Here is my web.xml thats inside the jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SampleServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is a sample servlet</description>
    <display-name>Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servletPackage.Servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: where is your web.xml?

Comment: @javaguy I have added the information

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way in which you are launching the Grid

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar -role hub -port 4444 -servlets servletPackage.Servlet
```

I am guessing that `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar` represents a jar that you downloaded from the Selenium [downloads](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) page.

since you are doing `java -jar` and since your jar does not contain the classes for `servletPackage.Servlet` the servlet is never getting registered to the Grid.

That explains

> The problem is when I hit the page
>   http://localhost:4444/grid/admin/Servlet I get a whoops page.

Choose one of the following :

1. You build a uber jar which includes both the selenium libraries and also your servlet classes in the same jar (that way only `java -jar` is sufficient)
2. You build a jar out of your `servletPackage.Servlet` class, drop it in the classpath and then resort to `java -cp selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar;myjar.jar -servlets servletPackage.Servlet` (Here use `;` to separate the jars if you are on windows and use ':' if you are on OSX/Unix)

After this you should see your servlet wired in.

> I've made a servlet for selenium grid and from what I can see i've
>   followed all of the information on the selenium (not much on there
>   actually) but I still dont get it.

Not entirely true in terms of the documentation. Have you referred to official documentation pages [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#customizing-the-grid) ?

> Edit: Here is my web.xml thats inside the jar

I doubt if you would need a `web.xml` here. From what I have seen in the Grid code, I don't think it refers to any `web.xml` for wrapping up the initialization.

Comment: Yeah I followed instructions on that site and it said nothing about including the jar in the class path. It also has no code examples. I guess i've been spoilt by things like C# where examples are all over MSDN. I'll give your suggestions a try. I've already built the jar out of my package so ill give that a shot.

Comment: Sadly that didnt work I got the following:

C:\Repos\selenium-grid\Package>java -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar;Servlet.jar" -servlets servletPackage.SampleServlet -role hub -port 4444
Unrecognized option: -servlets